# Good KML library on iOS

Tags: ios, parsing, kml

Would anyone know a good and easy-to-use library on iOS to parse KML in order to get all the polygons described in the file?

Comment: I've never seen one, but it's certainly not difficult to code one using NSXMLParser or one of the other XML libraries out there.  I recommend TouchXML.

Comment: That's what I finally did because none of the library I found seemed to work ! Personally I used TBXML which quite good and intuitive. Great thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ben can you please provide me that code snippet. I need to do kml parsing with google map ios sdk. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262736/how-to-load-kml-file-into-google-maps-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a promising one: https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML

Just researching myself.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the best one (among the various ones I found). Unfortunately, I didn't managed to make it work properly in my case. Hence, and as explained above, I finally decided to parse the kml myself with the xml parser TBXML... That's personally the solution I would recommend to you. Anyway, thanks for your help ! CU !

Answer (score 1):

You may find the KMLViewer example in the iOS sample code helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

This one seems to work well for me:
http://kmlframework.com/#license

The sample app lets you enter a URL to some KML, and it will display it.

It is free to use under the MIT license (which includes commercial use).