# How to add kml file into google_maps_flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, kml, google-maps-flutter

In [GoogleMaps](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) flutter, there isn't any support for KML file integration

I found this workaround https://brunozaranza.medium.com/google-maps-flutter-com-kml-e750c8c5b793

But it is only for android

Can anyone please tell me how to add KML file into google maps flutter for both android and iOS ?

Comment: You can check this same for Ios: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/kml  as per google maps doc

Comment: have you tried that in iOS? @HardikMehta ?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Still not https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60911 :(

Comment: if you're familiar with kotlin/swift you can create separate screens for ios and android in natively and invoke those screens using platform channels from flutter

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not the ideal solution but there are native options for handling kml with iOS devices. Take a look at this thread [Good KML library on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506407/good-kml-library-on-ios)